# Какая библиотека для парсинга на python3 будет самой оптимальной по скорости и относительно простой в использовании?

Tags: python, парсер, python-3.5

Передо мною стоит задача парсить каталоги Хотлайна или некоторых других сайтов с товарами (например: `http://hotline.ua/computer/bloki-pitaniya/`), собственно 32(пробежаться по них в цикле) страници по 24 товара = итого  768 товаров. Нужно зайти в каждую позиции и вытянуть там определенную инфу (цену/список магазинов и цен в них и т.д.)

*Или может у кого-то будет идея лучшей реализации которой поделится? :)*

Надо для этой задачи выбрать оптимальный вариант между скоростью и простотою использования(вменяемая документация). Потому прошу более опытных коллег дать совет, кто чем пользовался и какие впечатления?

Из самых популярных библиотек выделил несколько. В сети нашел не однозначные мнения по использованию библиотек:

- **lxml**

  > Самая лучшая, но не самая популярная. Эффективная и мощная, однако
  >   непроста в изучении.
- **BeautifulSoup**

  > Пишут что она дико медленная, и иногда криво работает и всё такое. А на
  >   некоторых форумах ее наоборот очень хвалят.
- **Grab**

  > Отличная библиотека, доходчивая документация на русском. Асинхронный
  >   многопоточный парсинг прилагается.
- **pyQuery**

  > «питоновский» порт для парсинга с использованием jQuery.

Comment: @stackflow так получается если использовать `BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')` это будет тоже самое что использовать саму `lxml`

Comment: вот у тебя уже 485 репутации, а, значит, хотя бы сейчас **пора** ознакомиться со **[справкой в целом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help)** и о том **[Какие вопросы лучше не задавать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)**

Comment: не очень полезно обсуждать производительность нетривиального кода, если этот код не показан. Напишите рабочую версию (используйте ту библиотеку , которую вы лучше всего знаете, и которая нужную задачу выполняет). *Измерьте* производительность. Если окажется, что недостаточно, и что дело не в скорости работы сервера, сети, если profiler показал, что именно библиотека распознавания html является узким местом, тогда имея рабочий код и конкретную цель на сколько ускорить необходимо, можно обсуждать производительность.